# KDB asof join giving incorrect results

Tags: join, kdb, q-lang

**I have a table of trades `Trades`:**

```
TradeID Stock   Timestamp
1       GOOG    2014.03.03 09:13:59.054
2       GOOG    2014.03.03 09:28:12.003
3       GOOG    2014.03.03 09:28:18.199
4       GOOG    2014.03.03 09:52:03.628
5       GOOG    2014.03.03 11:18:52.629
...
```

**and also a table of price tick data `Prices`:**

```
Stock   Timestamp               Bid         Ask
GOOG    2014.03.03 08:02:34.297 102.21      102.41
GOOG    2014.03.03 08:02:40.118 102.32      102.42
GOOG    2014.03.03 08:02:44.090 102.33      102.43
GOOG    2014.03.03 08:03:20.197 102.34      102.44
GOOG    2014.03.03 08:05:09.325 102.35      102.45
...
```

**When I do an [asof](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#aj-aj0-asof-join) join...**

```
aj[
    `Stock`Timestamp;
    Trades;
    update TimestampPrice:Timestamp from Prices  / let's me track which price gets joined
]
```

**...I get the wrong result:**

```
TradeID Stock   Timestamp                TimestampPrice             Bid     Ask
1       GOOG    2014.03.03 09:13:59.054  2014.03.03 08:05:09.325    102.35  102.45
2       GOOG    2014.03.03 09:28:12.003  2014.03.03 08:05:09.325    102.35  102.45
3       GOOG    2014.03.03 09:28:18.199  2014.03.03 08:05:09.325    102.35  102.45
4       GOOG    2014.03.03 09:52:03.628  2014.03.03 08:05:09.325    102.35  102.45
5       GOOG    2014.03.03 11:18:52.629  2014.03.03 10:31:45.043    102.24  102.35
6       GOOG    2014.03.03 11:33:52.021  2014.03.03 10:31:45.043    102.24  102.35
```

`Timestamp` shows the time of trade, while `TimestampPrice` shows the timestamp of the price data that was joined. Despite having price data ticking roughly every 30 secs, **the result of the `aj` joins on prices that are several hours away from the actual trade**! E.g., `TradeID=1` was traded at `09:13:59` but was joined on prices from `08:05:09`.

Also, I find it strange that the joined `TimestampPrice` suddenly jumps from `08:05:09` to `10:31:45`.

I have manually checked that there are no gaps in the data that could account for this.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: Interesting, I was able to get this working correctly using your data. What type is your Timestamp column?

Comment: I suspect the Timestamp is a mixed list instead of timestamp type... Think it should've been 2014.03.03T09:13:59.054 instead of 2014.03.03 09:13:59.054 with a space between date and time... Just want to make sure this is not typo...

Comment: In addition, also make sure the Timestamp column is sorted as aj assumes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In addition, also make sure the Timestamp column is sorted as aj
>   assumes it is

–  user2393012 Apr 9 at 8:47